# NGINX setting CORS headers for the `api` subdomain only

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cors

I've got an NGINX setup that proxies my app servers requests as follows:

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
  use epoll;
  accept_mutex on;
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  # Instead of using Rack::Deflater and having the application serer Gzip HTML and JSON requests from
  # the client, have the webserver compress them.

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 3;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
    application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
    application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
    application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

  underscores_in_headers on;

  server_tokens off;

  log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
  access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
  error_log logs/nginx/error.log;

  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;

  #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
  client_body_timeout <%= ENV['NGINX_CLIENT_BODY_TIMEOUT'] || 5 %>;

  upstream app_server {
      server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /app/public;
    client_max_body_size <%= ENV['NGINX_CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE'] || 1 %>M;
    server_name _

    location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
      # Have Nginx prefer to serve the *.gz file, since its already compressed and ready to go
      gzip_static on;

      # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;

      # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
      # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
      # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";

      # When serving fonts, we need to make sure we set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to '*'.
      location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)$ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      }

      break;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
  }
}
```

However, if users make a request to `api.mydomain.com`, I would like NGINX to add CORS headers to those requests, but only then.

So if the user makes a request to `app.mydomain.com` I do not want CORS header, but if they request to `api.mydomain.com` I would like them added.  Does anyone have any tips on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a specific `server` block for `api.mydomain.com`:

```
server {
  server_name api.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Authorization';
  }
}
```

Alternatively I guess you could use an `if ($host = "api.mydomain.com")` block:

```
if ($host = "api.mydomain.com") {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Authorization';
}
```